# Describing what $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ looks like

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given $A = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Im(e^{z}) > 0\}$, describe what the set looks like. Note: $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of the complex number $z$.

So if $z = x+iy$, then according to what we were given, $\Im{(e^z)} = \Im{(e^{x+iy})} = e^y >0$. But what does this mean graphically? Does it cover the entire complex-real plane?

Comment: $ \Im{(e^{x+iy})} \ne e^y $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z = x + iy$, then
$$
e^z = e^x \, e^{iy} = e^x (\cos y + i \sin y),
$$
so $\Im(e^z) = e^x \sin y$. Since $e^x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the upper half-plane condition that defines your set $A$ is equivalent to
$$
\sin y > 0.
$$

As sine is a periodic function, the inequality is satisfied on the union of open intervals
$$
\cdots (-2\pi, -\pi) \cup 
(0, \pi) \cup 
(2\pi, 3\pi) \cup \cdots
$$
or
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigl( 2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi \bigr) 
$$
and so $A$ is the union of horizontal strips with open boundaries
\begin{align}
A &= \mathbb{R} \times \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} 
\bigl( 2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi \bigr) \\
&= \bigl\{x + iy \in \mathbb{C} \mid 2n\pi < y < (2n+1)\pi 
\text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{Z} \bigr\}. 
\end{align}

[image: Horizontal strips in complex plane.]